# Small program to convert temperature in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program where a user enters a temperature that can be converted to Fahrenheit or Celsius dependent on the user. Conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit works as expected. However, from Fahrenheit to Celsius, it gives a hex answer.

I have tried to move the parenthesis and formula around, but nothing seems to give the expected result.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def fahrenheit(c):
 fahrenheit=c *9/5+32
 print (fahrenheit)

def celsius(f):
 celcius=5/9*(f-32)
 print (celsius)

#f= int (input("Please enter the temperature in fahrenheit"))
#c= int (input("Please enter the temperature in celcius"))
conversion= (input("Please enter which measurement to convert to fahrenheit or celsius"))

if conversion == "fahrenheit":
  c= int (input("Please enter the temperature in celcius"))
  fahrenheit (c)

elif conversion == "celsius":
  f= int (input("Please enter the temperature in fahrenheit"))
  celsius (f)
else:
  print ("Please enter the appropriate operator ")
```

Output of fahrenheit to celsius:

```
<function celsius at 0x7f539a933840>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give different variable names that don't clash with your function names. It's also good to `return` the return values instead of leaving it to the interpreter.

Comment: Thank you so much, changing the variable from the function name worked.

Answer (score 0):

As [@absolutelydevastated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56980714/6042824) said in the linked answer, your variable name should not clash with the function name. And, as suggested in the answer, `return` the calculated value instead of printing it in the function itself.

I would like to add a few more points.

- Give meaningful names. For example, instead of naming your function `fahrenheit`, name it `to_fahrenheit` as you are converting the temperature *to fahrenheit*.
- When asking the user what to convert, instead of expecting them to write the full word (Fahrenheit or Celsius), give them simple options like **f or c**.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the function name as you suggested and it helps the readability of it.